# is tcp header timestamp mandatory or optional? and how to generate tcp timestamp

Tags: networking, tcp

I noticed that in all tcp communications,
in the tcp header option parts, tcp timestamp is always there
is it mandatory or not?
so if there is no tcp timestamp in a tcp packet, the tcp client or server will reject it?

besides, I don't find any source snippets for generating tcp timestamps
can anyone provide some links or examples on how to generate tcp timestamps?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

TCP timestamps are not required, but can help in ordering packets in time. This likely would only matter when you have a lot of TCP retries going on. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_timestamps

A TCP packet will not be rejected for lack of a TCP timestamp.

Comment: thanks, are there any source snippets for generation of tcp timestamps?

Comment: From what I'v seen on the internet, there are no specific units. It's a 4-byte field that you drop your time into.  See http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/tcp/option008.htm and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa923592.aspx. It looks like the RFC was careful not to specify a unit. You can use a 32-bit representation of your system clock for example.

Comment: you meant just use a random number? then how to increase the number for the next packet?

Comment: You can use your system clock. I was just saying it doesn't specify if your LSB signifies seconds, nanoseconds, or microseconds or none of the above. That's up to you.